# Why when drawing a box using LineRenderer the connected points of the lines is not complete?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

It looks like depending on the camera view angle that there is kind of space in the connected points between the lines:

[image: Anim Box]

What I mean not connected or kind of pspaces in the connection points of the lines is marked here with blue circles:

[image]

The script:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using UnityEngine;

public class ShowMeshBounds : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject[] objectsToDraw;
    public GameObject prefabEffect;
    public Color color = Color.green;

    private Vector3 v3FrontTopLeft;
    private Vector3 v3FrontTopRight;
    private Vector3 v3FrontBottomLeft;
    private Vector3 v3FrontBottomRight;
    private Vector3 v3BackTopLeft;
    private Vector3 v3BackTopRight;
    private Vector3 v3BackBottomLeft;
    private Vector3 v3BackBottomRight;

    private float counter = 0;
    public bool animateLines;
    public float speed = 1f;

    private List<GameObject> allLines = new List<GameObject>();
    private List<GameObject> instancesToMove = new List<GameObject>();
    private Vector3 startPos;
    private Vector3 endPos;

    private void Start()
    {
        DrawObjects();
    }

    private void DrawObjects()
    {
        objectsToDraw = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("SpawnObject");

        for (int i = 0; i < objectsToDraw.Length; i++)
        {
            CalcPositons(objectsToDraw[i]);
            DrawBox();

            for (int x = 0; x < allLines.Count; x++)
            {

                allLines[x].transform.parent = objectsToDraw[i].transform;
            }
        }

        DuplicatePrefabEffects(1);

        StartCoroutine(moveStuff());
    }

    private void DuplicatePrefabEffects(int duplicationNumber)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < duplicationNumber; i++)
        {
            var go = Instantiate(prefabEffect);
            go.tag = "Duplicated Prefab";
            go.name = "Duplicated Prefab";
            instancesToMove.Add(go);
        }
    }

    void CalcPositons(GameObject objectToDrawTransform)
    {
        Bounds bounds = objectToDrawTransform.GetComponent<MeshFilter>().sharedMesh.bounds;

        Vector3 v3Center = bounds.center;
        Vector3 v3Extents = bounds.extents;

        v3FrontTopLeft = new Vector3(v3Center.x - v3Extents.x, v3Center.y + v3Extents.y, v3Center.z - v3Extents.z);  // Front top left corner
        v3FrontTopRight = new Vector3(v3Center.x + v3Extents.x, v3Center.y + v3Extents.y, v3Center.z - v3Extents.z);  // Front top right corner
        v3FrontBottomLeft = new Vector3(v3Center.x - v3Extents.x, v3Center.y - v3Extents.y, v3Center.z - v3Extents.z);  // Front bottom left corner
        v3FrontBottomRight = new Vector3(v3Center.x + v3Extents.x, v3Center.y - v3Extents.y, v3Center.z - v3Extents.z);  // Front bottom right corner
        v3BackTopLeft = new Vector3(v3Center.x - v3Extents.x, v3Center.y + v3Extents.y, v3Center.z + v3Extents.z);  // Back top left corner
        v3BackTopRight = new Vector3(v3Center.x + v3Extents.x, v3Center.y + v3Extents.y, v3Center.z + v3Extents.z);  // Back top right corner
        v3BackBottomLeft = new Vector3(v3Center.x - v3Extents.x, v3Center.y - v3Extents.y, v3Center.z + v3Extents.z);  // Back bottom left corner
        v3BackBottomRight = new Vector3(v3Center.x + v3Extents.x, v3Center.y - v3Extents.y, v3Center.z + v3Extents.z);  // Back bottom right corner

        v3FrontTopLeft = objectToDrawTransform.transform.TransformPoint(v3FrontTopLeft);
        v3FrontTopRight = objectToDrawTransform.transform.TransformPoint(v3FrontTopRight);
        v3FrontBottomLeft = objectToDrawTransform.transform.TransformPoint(v3FrontBottomLeft);
        v3FrontBottomRight = objectToDrawTransform.transform.TransformPoint(v3FrontBottomRight);
        v3BackTopLeft = objectToDrawTransform.transform.TransformPoint(v3BackTopLeft);
        v3BackTopRight = objectToDrawTransform.transform.TransformPoint(v3BackTopRight);
        v3BackBottomLeft = objectToDrawTransform.transform.TransformPoint(v3BackBottomLeft);
        v3BackBottomRight = objectToDrawTransform.transform.TransformPoint(v3BackBottomRight);
    }

    void DrawBox()
    {
        SpawnLineGenerator(v3FrontTopLeft, v3FrontTopRight, color);
        SpawnLineGenerator(v3FrontTopRight, v3FrontBottomRight, color);
        SpawnLineGenerator(v3FrontBottomRight, v3FrontBottomLeft, color);
        SpawnLineGenerator(v3FrontBottomLeft, v3FrontTopLeft, color);

        SpawnLineGenerator(v3BackTopLeft, v3BackTopRight, color);
        SpawnLineGenerator(v3BackTopRight, v3BackBottomRight, color);
        SpawnLineGenerator(v3BackBottomRight, v3BackBottomLeft, color);
        SpawnLineGenerator(v3BackBottomLeft, v3BackTopLeft, color);

        SpawnLineGenerator(v3FrontTopLeft, v3BackTopLeft, color);
        SpawnLineGenerator(v3FrontTopRight, v3BackTopRight, color);
        SpawnLineGenerator(v3FrontBottomRight, v3BackBottomRight, color);
        SpawnLineGenerator(v3FrontBottomLeft, v3BackBottomLeft, color);
    }

    void SpawnLineGenerator(Vector3 start, Vector3 end, Color color)
    {
        GameObject myLine = new GameObject();

        myLine.tag = "FrameLine";
        myLine.name = "FrameLine";

        myLine.AddComponent<LineRenderer>();
        myLine.AddComponent<EndHolder>();
        myLine.GetComponent<EndHolder>().EndVector = end;
        LineRenderer lr = myLine.GetComponent<LineRenderer>();
        lr.material = new Material(Shader.Find("Particles/Alpha Blended Premultiply"));
        lr.startColor = color;
        lr.useWorldSpace = false;
        lr.endColor = color;
        lr.startWidth = 0.1f;//0.03f;
        lr.endWidth = 0.1f;//0.03f;
        lr.SetPosition(0, start);
        lr.SetPosition(1, start);

        allLines.Add(myLine);
    }

    IEnumerator moveStuff()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < allLines.Count; i++)
        {
            counter = 0;
            endPos = allLines[i].GetComponent<EndHolder>().EndVector;

            var dist = Vector3.Distance(endPos, startPos);
            while (counter < 25)//dist > 0f)
            {
                dist = Vector3.Distance(instancesToMove[0].transform.position, endPos);
                counter++;
                endPos = allLines[i].GetComponent<EndHolder>().EndVector;
                startPos = allLines[i].GetComponent<LineRenderer>().GetPosition(0);

                instancesToMove[0].transform.position =
                    Vector3.MoveTowards(startPos, endPos, counter / 25f * speed);

                allLines[i].GetComponent<LineRenderer>().SetPosition(1, instancesToMove[0].transform.position);//tempPos);

                yield return null;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

What I want is to create animate the linerenderer lines and create smooth complete box.

Comment: It seems that a Line Renderer is not the kind of thing you want to use for that. If you use a 3d model you won't have the described problem. To get a view like this you can use a wireframe or outline shader (or something similar). Take a look on the asset store or github there are plenty of examples how to create one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What's happening here is that the line has reached the corner of the cube correctly. However, this doesn't take into account  that the line has a width, which gives the appearance.

You could tell one line to keep going until the cube is visually complete, however it seems a linerenderer may not be suited to your task.

[The red line here shows what's happening internally](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V3zkL.jpg)